# counterdown timer in react dont work properly

Tags: reactjs, timer, counter, lifecycle

I am beginner.
I have a question, I have made a counter timer in React, but unfortunately, it doesn't work properly.
I can't find a mistake, Could someone help me?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function CountDown() {
 let [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(3);
 let [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(59);
 let [hours, setHours] = useState(3);

 useEffect(() => {
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
     setCounddownTimer();
     console.log("i am working", { seconds, minutes, hours });
     return () => clearInterval(interval);
   }, 1000);
 }, []);
 const setCounddownTimer = () => {
   if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
     timerReset();
   } else if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
     console.log({ seconds, minutes, hours });
     setHours(--hours);
     setMinutes(59);
     setSeconds(59);
   } else if (seconds === 0) {
     setSeconds(59);
     setMinutes(--minutes);
   } else {
     setSeconds(--seconds);
   }
 };
 const timerReset = () => {
   setSeconds(59);
   setMinutes(59);
   setHours(3);
 };
 const addLeadingZero = (number) => {
   return number < 10 ? "0" + number : number;
 };
 const style = {
   "text-align": "center",
   "font-weight": "bold",
   color: "#cf0000"
 };
 return (
   <div style={style}>
     {addLeadingZero(hours)}:{addLeadingZero(minutes)}:
     {addLeadingZero(seconds)}
   </div>
 );
}
```

I am also paste a link to codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hopper-f9dy4?file=/src/App.js:0-1277

Comment: can you include your expectations and what specifically you are having trouble with?

Comment: ok, seconds decrease by 1 to a value of 0, next minutes change to 58. Next, the magic happens. Seconds are equal to 59, and minutes still decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect`'s `return` statement was *inside* the `setInterval()`. It should be outside.

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setCounddownTimer();
  console.log("i am working", { seconds, minutes, hours });
}, 1000);

return () => clearInterval(interval);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also, you should've put `hours, minutes, seconds` in `useEffect`'s dependency array, since rendering depends on these 3 states. Otherwise the seconds will count down till the timer reaches 03:58:59, but then the minutes will start counting down.

Comment: Thank you so much, of course, it should be outside. I missed it.

Comment: FYI the dependency array is the second person in useEffect where you have an empty array currently.